# How to print something in delay in Lodash

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash, yarnpkg

I have an exercise in JS/Lodash to print ten songs in delay of 5 seconds each. The problem is, that I get 10 times the song, that index is 14th.
I don't know where I made a mistake, would be grateful for any help.

```
const utwory = [{
    "author": "Queen",
    "song": "Bohemian Rhapsody",
    "place": 1,
    "change": 0
  },
  {
    "author": "Deep Purple",
    "song": "Child in time",
    "place": 2,
    "change": 2
  }
]

function ex7() {
  let i = 0;


  while (i < 10) {
    _.delay(function(arr) {
      console.log(arr[i].author + " " + arr[i].song)
    }, 10000, utwory)

    i += 1
  }
}
ex7()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the function inside the `_.delay()` is invoked, it uses the current value of `i`, which is 10. You can solve it by changing the loop to a for loop, and use `let i`, so `i` would the it's value inside the closure.

In addition, you can avoid this problem by passing the current item `utwory[i]` to the delay, and just `console.log()` the item in the callback.

I've used both methods here:

```js
const utwory = [{"author":"Queen","song":"Bohemian Rhapsody","place":1,"change":0},{"author":"Deep Purple","song":"Child in time","place":2,"change":2}]

function ex7() {
  for(let i = 0; i < utwory.length; i++) {
    _.delay(function({ author, song }) {
      console.log(`${author} ${song}`)
    }, 1000 * (i + 1), utwory[i]) // set the item to print here
  }
}

ex7()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've just changed while to for and it is working now, but I don't really understand why it takes i=11? When it goes to first triggering of delay, i = 0, so why does it take 11 as a value?

Comment: Sorry, the latest is 10 because the loop ends when `i < 10` fails because `i` is 10. Updated the answer.

Comment: it doesn't matter, it was not the case- the case was still, why does it take 10, when going into first delay i = 0? 2nd question is how to make a 5 seconds gap between EACH song, because now it prints all songs after 5 seconds?

Comment: The internal functions are called from the time their invoked, and all of them are invoked almost together. You'll need to increment the time by yourself - I use `1000 * (i + 1)` in the snippet.

Comment: I understand and I don't understand. So it doesn't work like this? : We are in loop, the function inside the delay is invoked after the time which we set, then, we got to 2nd iteration of loop, and again the function is invoked after the time we set?

Comment: The delay is a function that is invoked immediately, and sets the timeout for invoking the callback (the function inside the delay). The 2nd delay does the same for it's internal function, and so on.

Comment: ok, so why when I use 5000, are all the songs printed together if the delay of the callback is 5000?

Comment: All of them are invoked 5000 ms after being called, so you, but if you if do `5000 * (i + 1)` you'll have 5000 ms delay between each call.

Comment: yeah, I know what to do, to make them 5000ms between each call, but I still don't understand the thing.
If we are in loop, we call first function after 5 secs, then, we are in loop for 2nd time and again the function should be invoked after 5 secs, why doesn't it work like that?

Comment: Ok, I probably understand, so the whole loop is done in let's say 1ms, and "in the memory" all of the delay functions are waiting with 5 sec delay, so they are invoked almost together?

Comment: Exactly. The initial call of delay just sets the timers. The internal functions are called when the time timer is done - 5000 ms in the original order in which the timers were set.